# Would anyone know where I could find information on how to make stretchable box (while holding down a mouse) on HTML page ?

Tags: javascript, events

What I'm trying to find is a way to make something similar to the Google Calendar or Tungle where the user has the ability, when making an event, to set the start time and end time by stretching/shrinking a rectangle. I just don't know what I should be looking for...

Comment: You might look at jQuery Fullcalendar, which is a very good Google Calendar clone and implements this feature. The source is pretty well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/